# Moderate localized water damage that's hard to inspect from above

Tags: attic, water-damage

I have water damage in the ceiling along one end of the house. It wasn't detected for some time because it was in a room we don't often go into.

[image: Water damage]

There was an unpleasant musty smell, but it has abated. Still, I was worried about mold on the other side. Unfortunately, it is difficult to inspect the location:

[image: Leak location in attic]

The area of the leak is around the middle of the flashlight spot. We think the leak was from blown rain around the place where an AC line entered the house. That has been caulked. Assuming the damage doesn't get worse, is it safe just to repair it from below without examining it from above?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see ANY discoloration (black stains, etc.) on the studs or roof joists. Therefore, it’s minor and hasn’t damaged the wood structurally or caused mold.

The damage is what I’d classify as insignificant. It’s not worth tearing up your attic to see the damage from “above”.

If you’re not sure you’ve stopped the leak, you could take an ink pen (a pencil won’t work) and draw an outline around the perimeter of the leak/stain. Keep an eye on it for one rainy season, then fix the ceiling. If it leaks again, keep a journal and make note if it leaks during heavy rain, strong winds, rain coming from the west, etc. It’ll help you find the “real” leak later.